# Android Kernel panic Debugging - Android 10

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

I am currently building a lineage rom for SM-P555 Samsung Galaxy Tab A device

Full dmesg log https://hastebin.com/ifavimodum.yaml

The tablet hangs at boot up as shown in https://pasteboard.co/K68YclJ.jpg

How to fix this problem ?
What are the other logs to find the problem ?
How to enable full kernel debug logging for Android 10 lineage ROM ?

Comment: Try building a build with permissive selinux, if the build boots then you have to adress denials. You should always set selinux to permissive during bringups

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried that yesterday, but the same issue surfaced too.

Answer (score 0):

In android 8 logs are located in `\data\log\android_logs\...` . Kernel messages are called `kmsgcat-log_timestamp_.gz`

Try this path. May be useful.